# modal not showing when the content is under of setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have made notification using ajax

im trying to open modal clicking on the content of notification with setInterval

when the content of my notification out of setInterval the modal works/popup properly but when under setInterval modal not popup even click function not read on

[my images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6RzB.png)

code: modal popup properly but not updated every 3seconds

```
msgbox = "";
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin-message.php",
    data: {msgbox: msgbox},
    success: function(result) 
    {
        $('#message_content').html(result);
    }  
});
```

this code is updated every 3secs but the modal is not popup when on click

```
setInterval(function() 
{
    msgbox = "";
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "admin-message.php",
        data: {msgbox: msgbox},
        success: function(result) 
        {
            $('#message_content').html(result);
        }  
    }); 
}, 3000);
```

this is my admin-message php code:

```
$sqlapplicant = "SELECT * FROM admin_notification ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqlapplicant); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<div id='.$row['id'].' class="message_content"> 
   //content here image, name, message...
  </div>';
}
```

jquery click on notification box

```
$(".message_content").click(function()
{
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "message_modal.php",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(result) 
        {
            $('#inbox_popup').html(result);
            $("#inbox_modal").modal('show');

        }  
    });
```

message_modal.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    //sql query update read status to 1
    echo '<div class="modal fade" id="inbox_modal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                        //modal content etcc....
                        </div>
                    </div>';
}
```

my modal pop ups fine when the admin-message.php ajax is not under of setInterval

i dont know what is the problem why my modal is not poping up when the ajax is under of setInterval

Comment: Please post also the relevant html and/or other code.

Comment: Also have you checked the error callback? Maybe that provides helpful information.

Comment: im sorry, i think i don't have any error for my html or php code cuz the setInterval only preventing my modal in my notification also no callback at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted enough of your code - for example, where is the javascript/jQuery that binds  `whatever-is-being-clicked-on` to the click event?

Also, when you say `the code is updated every 3 seconds` - what do you mean by that? What code is being updated? How is it being updated?

A common problem most of us have run into at some point, is when that click event is bound to some js code. For example, if you add the `whatever-is-being-clicked-on` element ***after*** the DOM has been initially rendered, then you must use the `.on()` method:

```
$(document).on('btnSomething', 'click', function(){
    //your ajax etc code goes here
});
```

This is called ***event delegation*** and you can read more about it [here at api.jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and [here at SmashingMagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/seven-javascript-things-i-wish-i-knew-much-earlier-in-my-career/#event-delegation).

Also, if you are injecting any javascript/jQuery code after the DOM has been rendered, then again you must use `.on()`

The code you posted above is not obviously incorrect, so the problem must be somewhere else. Therefore, if using `.on()` does not solve the problem, then please update your question to provide more of your code.

---

Thanks for posting the additional code. I am still not entirely sure what is happening (i.e. what the user clicks *first*, then what happens, and what the user clicks *next*, and what happens then...) **BUT** I can see a couple of things:

1. This is what I was talking about above:

   $(".message_content").click(function()

   It appears the div with class `.message_content` is injected via AJAX, right? So, you cannot use the above code to bind the click event *(BECAUSE `.click()` must be bound when the DOM is initially rendered, and will not work for elements that are later added to the DOM)* ***Solution:*** use event delegation:

   $(document).on('click', ".message_content", function()

***However,*** is that the correct div/class to bind to a click event? Your earlier js code shows the ".message_content" div being added as the body to a message box...?

Another thought: ***make sure*** there are never two elements in the DOM that have the same `ID`. Remember that IDs and Classes are nearly the same! If there is any danger of duplicate IDs, just switch to using a class. *(You know, Bootstrap is super-popular, and they do everything via classes! IDs are helpful, but not necessary - Bootstrap doesn't use them... you don't need them, not really.)* Doing so will make your life easier - and that's what this is all about, right? *Making your life easier!*

Comment: yup message-content is div of message
i never duplicate my id just the class only

Comment: So is that the right thing for the user to click on? The body of the message? Anyway, that doesn't matter - probably it is the right thing. The point is: if it is being added (aka "injected") via AJAX, then ***you must use*** `.on()` to bind the click event or it simply won't work.

Comment: Glad to help, Del. Happy coding.